# Error when try to run the command "npm run start-solana-main" to run on solana CLI

Tags: anchor, solana, anchor-solana, solana-transaction-instruction

I have deployed my contract on the Solana mainnet and when I run

```
npm run start-solana-main
```

The server started running successfully but when I post a file to the service, it shows me error that

> The declared program id does not matched the actual program id

This is actual screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the `anchor.toml` file you have program

```
[programs.localnet]
program = "ABTiPAFguUxFVohT1xPkfTc3YoJL9vpyp4oRA9RBiGqR"
```

and inside `lib.rs`, you have

```
declare_id!("ABTiPAFguUxFVohT1xPkfTc3YoJL9vpyp4oRA9RBiGqR");
```

Error states that they do not match

Comment: I have used same key in the both "anchor.toml" and  "lib.rs". Is that wrong? If yes, where should I put my program id and pubkey?

Comment: Please help and tell me what to do.